# Vb.net List within a list

Tags: vb.net, list, datagridview, listboxitem

So far I have the following code below. How to display each list value to textboxes?

```
    Dim list As New List(Of String)

    list.Add(dgvData.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString)
    list.Add(dgvData.SelectedCells(1).Value.ToString)
    list.Add(dgvData.SelectedCells(2).Value.ToString)
    list.Add(dgvData.SelectedCells(4).Value.ToString)

    Dim val As String
    For Each val In list
        ' MsgBox(val)
    Next
```

Comment: Do the `TextBoxes` already exist?

Comment: Yes, they already exist.

Comment: Then put the `TextBoxes` into an array and use a `For Each` loop.  Get rid of that `List(Of String)` altogether and use `dgvData.SelectedCells.Count` to determine the loop counter limit.

Answer (score 0):

Add your code in the CellEnter Event. You don't need to declare the list.

```
Private Sub YourDataGrid_CellEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles YourDataGrid.CellEnter

txtbox1.Text = YourDataGrid.Item(col, row).Value.ToString
txtbox2.Text = YourDataGrid.Item(col, row).Value.ToString
txtbox3.Text = YourDataGrid.Item(col, row).Value.ToString
txtbox4.Text = YourDataGrid.Item(col, row).Value.ToString

end sub
```